# MYSQL select distinct does not show all records

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing data like:

```
customers_id | date_altered
1            | 2012-04-06
1            | 2013-04-09
2            | 2014-02-02
...
```

and so on. There are around 12k records. I want to get the last date_altered for each customer. I am using the follow query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `customers_id`, max(date_altered) FROM bp_booking
```

which returns only 1 row. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just use "group by" function for getting the correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `customers_id`,
max(date_altered)
FROM bp_booking
group by `customers_id`
```

Comment: you are  most welcome !! And also check the answer from Gordon Linoff, in case of group by you dont need distinct to be in the query.

Answer (score 3):

You want a `group by`, not `distinct`:

```
SELECT customers_id, max(date_altered)
FROM bp_booking
GROUP BY customers_id;
```